# hopen returns `hopen when trying to connect to localhost

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to establish a very basic connection between 2 q processes.

I start one listening on port 5000 using

```
    $ q -p 5000
```

I leave that running and then start a new q process from my terminal and try and connect, but get the output 'hopen

```
    q)h:hopen `:localhost:5000
    `hopen
```

There seem to be lots of resources about hopen and establishing connections, and this step is usually breezed over as simple! But has driven me crazy, and cant find any reference to `hopen error

Answer (score 1):

I think that error would indicate that hopen is not defined.
should be defined as `<:` in k

```
q)hopen
<:
```

If it's not something may be wrong with your q.k in $QHOME

Comment: Thank you very much.
I diff'd my q.k with the q.k in the original download and they were the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had been using a third party q binary in q/l32/q.
I replaced that with the original q binary and it started working.

Thank you very much for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if there is anything defined in q.q which modifies any of the IPC handlers. .z.po is invoked on a open connection and could be set to do something unexpected. Out of the box this q.q file should contain a header for your q console and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks - no there was just the header in there